# How to get own_reactions for child reactions? Likes of comments for example

Tags: python, getstream-io

In the documentation there's a way to get the own_reactions of someone's activity included, but haven't found a way to get the own_reactions (or own_child_reactions) of another reaction.

**For example, getting the own likes of a comment, to check whether to display to the user that they already liked that comment.**

This is how the documentation shows to get own_reactions for activities.

```
# read bob's timeline and include most recent reactions to all activities and her own reactions
client.feed("timeline", "bob").get(
    reactions={"own": True, "recent": True, "counts": True}, user_id="bob"
)
```

Wondering if there's something similar for reactions? Or having them also load own_reactions (of the reactions) from the activity fetching outright.

Would be useful because there could be many likes of a comment, and right now the only way (that I've found) is to fetch all the possible likes (as many times as required) for any given comment, just to check whether a user already liked given comment.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Valentin,
can you try add `with_own_children=True`

example
`client.feed("timeline", "bob").get(
    reactions={"own": True, "recent": True, "counts": True}, user_id="bob",with_own_children=True)`

Comment: @thesyncim thanks, that worked!